How to get client ID for google_sign_in_web
I need to read my app's client ID to sign in via google_sign_in_web.
I found this command:
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  clientId: const String.fromEnvironment('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
);

and I added my client ID (taken from the Google Credentials API) as a meta tag in web/index.html:
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">

However String.fromEnvironment('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID') returns null, what am I missing?
